# How do i get date from database other than GMT format?

Tags: java

Trying to get a time stored in a datadase.
`select dbtimezone from dual` gives me -07:00
I am using Java program to get the Date from Oracle 
Column i type of Date.

while i am fetching the time in my java program  am getting it as GMT.
actually i want the time as it is there in database not converted time.
Though i can convert back to -07:00 , i am seeking another way to do because conversion always depends on the *dbtimezone* of the database using.
Can any one help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting the date from the database (show us your code)? Beware that `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp` don't contain information about timezones.

Comment: i am using EO model framework . where i will specify calue class name as `NSCalendarDate` in `plist` and in java class i am converting the value into `toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That oracle just has one timezone can make life difficult if you deal with different timezones. I've always thought life was easier if you consider timezone a view artifact and
represent all times as UTC, then convert in the view. You put the timezone information someplace in the database and convert accordingly.

...actually getting that right can get interesting because you don't want to make the same mistake of being too general again. For example, a client may be based in a particular timezone, but have offices in many. Though an office is in a particular timezone, the activity relating to the time may involve a different timezone etc.

Comment: The problem is i have some data already. and since i know dbtimzone i can convert those values also .. i want to make that independent of the timezone if db. thats what i am trying.

Comment: Will you have data from different time zones?

Comment: yes in the sense i am accessing two different DB having two differenet timezone with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

See `java.util.TimeZone`, more specifically the `getOffset` methods, which return the number of milliseconds to add to the UTC time to get local time.  Note that it also considers the daylight saving time.

Comment: i dont want to convert the time which is saved in the database , i just want to display the value as such in db but while fetching i am getting a value which is converted to GMT in the entity.